# Handle FFMPEG dependency

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, dependencies, homebrew

I'm developping an [application](https://github.com/phonations/joker) (using the [Qt framework](http://qt.io) that has several dependencies like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org). Since I'm mostly developping for the *MacOS* plateform, I use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to manage my dependencies like *ffmpeg*.

As a result, I'm facing problem with unexpected API changes when the brew formula changes.

*Homebrew* mainteners advice me it's a bad practice to handle dependencies via brew. So I wonder what would be the best option?

I'm thinking about adding *ffmpeg* as a submodule of my project. What's your thought about it?

Comment: do you intend to build ffmpeg?

Comment: I want to link my software with a specific version of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a specific release of some library which conflicts with default as supplied then

```
uninstall current release

download source of desired release https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases

decompress source code into some location then cd into there
```

issue as yourself

```
./configure
```

carefully examine output and if no sign of ERROR and its finding upstream libraries correctly then issue as yourself one of the following

```
make       # only uses one CPU core still works but slower than -jxxx
make -j4   # to speed up make and you have a dual core CPU
make -j8   # to speed up make and you have a quad core CPU
```

now examine output of make for and errors ... you typically can ignore compile warnings  ... if all seems in order then issue (linux/OSX)

```
sudo make install
```

this will dist the libraries and executables to the standard locations which are visible for subsequent linking by downstream apps

Now you can compile your downstream code as normal to link to your freshly disted libraries from ffmpeg (there are many)

Above is the simplest case given that you already have installed the developer utilities necessary to compile source (compilers,linkers, ...)

If above fails due to missing or incorrect version of upstream librarie(s), repeat similar steps for those first then return back to compiling ffmpeg (recursive descent into library dependency install madness) ... I find compiling massive numbers of open source libraries easier and more standardized on linux than OSX ... YMMV

Comment: Thank you for your post! But there is still some dark point with the step you provide: ffmpeg will be install in /usr/local but isn't is reserved to brew?

Comment: No, /usr/local/  is for any end user installed code (not just brew) ... typically system installed code goes into directly into /usr/  .... if you poke about in a well used system you can see the variety of libraries appearing in either location

Comment: ok so your answer is far too verbose because I already know how to compile ffmpeg but let's hope it'll help future developer!